# Raster>Extraction>Clip Raster by Mask Layer not outputting an attribute table for clipped area. QGIS v3.34.1

Tags: qgis

I have a raster layer that I wanted to clip via Extract by Mask Layer with a vector polygon(s) layer. After the process completed the resulting clipped raster has no attribute table at all, just gray band symbology that holds no meaning to me (see output below this paragraph), where prior to the operation both the input raster and the mask vector had attribute tables.

[image: Output]

The Geotiff file I am using as my input raster does have an AT. I can view it by right-clicking the raster layer in the lefthand pane, as well as view the data associated with individual pixels using the 'Identify Feature' tool. QGIS also has a 'RasterAttributeTable' plugin, which I have installed. I took a screenshot, which you can see here:

[image: Input Raster depicted has both an attribute table and each pixel displays the same categories of fields when using the Identify tool]

The raster and all its related data come from the US Forest Service.  It can be found [here](https://www.fs.usda.gov/rds/archive/Catalog/RDS-2021-0074) along with the metadata.

The best case scenario for me would be that the two attribute tables be combined to one in the new raster layer, but if I had to choose one or the other then I need a modified (clipped) version of the original raster more.

Any tips?

Comment: Hi @Babel, yes I must be confused and perhaps am not using the correct terminology.  However the Geotiff file I am using as my raster does have an AT.  I can view it by right-clicking the raster layer in the lefthand pane, as well as view the data associated with individual pixels using the 'Identify Feature' tool.  QGIS also has a 'RasterAttributeTable' plugin.  I took a screenshot, which you can see here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wxYO24TGd4TajUMYlW1RFQUtdSPPFVx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Done (see revised post). As you can see from my post history I am new to GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can embed screenshots from the clipboard directly in the question - just use Paste (Ctrl+V). That makes for a better question. Are you currently using the RasterAttributeTable plugin or not. Not clear from your question. Maybe consider adding a small sample of your data (input, mask, output) that prospective answerers can download.

Comment: Hi Tom, I've embedded screenshots of the both the input and output rasters, and linked the source of the input raster dataset.