# Raster Attribute Table not getting output with Extract by Mask Layer (QGIS v3.34.1)

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster layer that I wanted to clip via Extract by Mask Layer with a vector polygon(s) layer. After the process completed the resulting clipped raster has no attribute table at all, just gray band symbology that holds no meaning to me (see output below this paragraph), where prior to the operation both the input raster and the mask vector had attribute tables.

[image: Output]

The Geotiff file I am using as my input raster does have an AT. I can view it by right-clicking the raster layer in the lefthand pane, as well as view the data associated with individual pixels using the 'Identify Feature' tool. QGIS also has a 'RasterAttributeTable' plugin, which I have installed. I took a screenshot, which you can see here:

[image: Input Raster depicted has both an attribute table and each pixel displays the same categories of fields when using the Identify tool]

The raster and all its related data come from the US Forest Service.  It can be found [here](https://www.fs.usda.gov/rds/archive/Catalog/RDS-2021-0074) along with the metadata.

The best case scenario for me would be that the two attribute tables be combined to one in the new raster layer, but if I had to choose one or the other then I need a modified (clipped) version of the original raster more.

Any tips?

Comment: Do not repost the same question. Rather edit the initial question to make it clearer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471599/rasterextractionclip-raster-by-mask-layer-not-outputting-an-attribute-table-fo